# Experiment with Bool Array

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I am doing a little experiment with boolean data type in cpp. 
here is my code:

```
bool **darray;
darray=new bool* [3];
int i=0;
while(i<3)
{
    darray[i]=new bool [5];
    i++;
}
int m,n;
for(m=0;m<3;m++)
{
    for(n=0;n<5;n++)
    {
        cin>>darray[m][n];
    }

}
for(m=0;m<3;m++)
{
    for(n=0;n<5;n++)
    {
        cout<<darray[m][n]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I know that for any non-zero input the result stored will be 1.
But soon as I enter any number greater than 1, the number stored in array is 1, rest of the elements of the array is set to 0 and the for loops halts there. 
e.g If I enter the number 95 at first iteration of for loop, the output is :

```
95 
1   0   0   0   0   //
0   0   0   0   0   // This is output
0   0   0   0   0   //
```

Please suggest me why this is happening. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When all your arrays are of static size, don't use dynamic allocation. If you are using c++11 use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) else "normal" arrays like `bool array[3][5];`. If you need arrays of dynamic size, consider [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You already have four memory leaks in your shown code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `state of std::cin is getting corrupted ( Or more specifically it's fail bit is set) as expected output (integer) doesn't match given data type (bool)`. So, after reading `95`, you can't read further *unless you clear that flag*

This is good example where you should check the state of stream after/before reading data from it.

Comment: It's not getting corrupted. It just has `failbit` set.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I believe it's same as you can't read further without clearing it...

Comment: @MikeSeymour actually I think it is `bad` bit, not fail.

Comment: OK, if that's what you mean by "corrupted", then I suppose you're right. That's rather an odd use of the word though; it would usually mean that the object is in an unrecoverably invalid state.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: No, it's `failbit` (see C++11 22.4.2.1.2
/6). In general, `failbit` indicates that an operation failed but the stream is still usable after clearing (as it is here), while `badbit` indicates an unrecoverable error.

Comment: @MikeSeymour ahh my mistake. I wrote a small program to test which of the two is raised and then confused the outputs...

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that reading a bool from the number `95` raises the `fail` bit of `cin`(You can verify that by printing `cin.fail()` at the end of your code). This means that the value passed when reading a bool value is not a proper format for a bool. All read operations will read nothing, because reading has already 'failed'. In essence `95` is not a valid bool value and `cin` does not know how to read it and could not possibly know what to do from this moment on(as it can not know if its state is sane).

Answer (score 0):

`95` is no valid input for reading a `bool` using `istream` (which `cin` is).

To detect such an error, write:

```
if (!(cin >> darray[m][n])) {
    cerr >> "This is no bool!" >> endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Or recover in some way from the error by repeating trying to read the input.